# pyenv install: build failed trying to install python 3.5.0 on OS X 11.6

Tags: python, command-line, pyenv, build-dependencies

Trying to install python version 3.5.0 with pyenv so that I can install an older version of scipy.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
(base) ➜  ~ pyenv install 3.5.0
Installing openssl-1.0.2k...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_5/fskpxlbd7ng8vv8p8t9z7l3r0000gn/T/python-build.20220404133720.51020
Results logged to /var/folders/_5/fskpxlbd7ng8vv8p8t9z7l3r0000gn/T/python-build.20220404133720.51020.log

Last 10 log lines:
      _dgram_write in libcrypto.a(bss_dgram.o)
      _RAND_query_egd_bytes in libcrypto.a(rand_egd.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
(base) ➜  ~
```

I'm guessing I don't have build dependencies but not sure how to determine which ones/how to install? Installing newer versions of python with pyenv is working fine.

Already tried:

Uninstall the old tools

$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Reinstall Xcode Command line tools

$ xcode-select --install

Install python using pyenv

$ pyenv install 3.5.0

Comment: It is curious that you're running into problems with "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386" — that implies you're trying to build a 32-bit version of Python rather than a 64-bit version (which would mention `x86_64` instead).  It may well be that the 32-bit libraries are not available any more for macOS Big Sur, but it is surprising that the configuration steps did not spot that.