# PyEnv BUILD FAILED installing past versions of Python on MacOS

Tags: python, xcode, macos, homebrew, pyenv

When trying to install past versions of `Python` using `PyEnv`, for example `Python 3.6.14`, I run into a **build failed** error. The command I am using is

`$ pyenv install 3.6.14`

The error I receive is

```
Downloading Python-3.6.14.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.14/Python-3.6.14.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.14...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.5.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/fj/7zh0_8qd1n76wwr6q1d47ywm0000gn/T/python-build.20220906233806.36658
Results logged to /var/folders/fj/7zh0_8qd1n76wwr6q1d47ywm0000gn/T/python-build.20220906233806.36658.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am able to download newer versions with no trouble, including versions of `Python 3.8` and onward. I can download select versions of `Python 3.7`, one version of `Python 3.6`, and none earlier than that. Here are the versions I've been able to download:

`3.10.5   3.10.6  3.6.15  3.7.12  3.7.13  3.8.13  3.9.12  3.9.13  3.9.5`

For some context, I am a graduate student learning about data engineering and foresee using older versions of `Python` in a virtual environment. I am aware that I could do something similar in `Docker`, but am interested in doing this via virtual environment.

My environment/framework versions are

- `MacOS Monterey 12.5.1`
- `pyenv 2.3.4`
- `Homebrew 3.5.10`
- `Xcode 13.3.1`
- Global Python is `Python 3.9.12`
- Because it is part of the error, I also feel it is necessary to say I have `Apple clang version 13.1.6`

I've read [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551557/pyenv-build-failed-installing-python-on-macos) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741992/pyenv-install-build-failed-trying-to-install-python-3-5-0-on-os-x-11-6), but none worked. I've tried uninstalling and installing `Xcode` and `Homebrew`, but no dice. Same with trying `--patch`or installing other `Homebrew` libraries such as `brew install readline xz` and `brew install openssl`.  I am open to other ways to install previous versions of `Python`, but would prefer to operate through `PyEnv`.